# Iot device and Django rest framework back-end security

Tags: security, django-rest-framework, iot

We have an Iot device that collect some data and send it to our DRF backend with https requests,this endpoints are't protected and anyone can send request to them,my question is how to protect this endpoints?usual auth methods does't work here due we are dealing with device not a human.
limits:
we can't set header to requests from device side.
device have a low storage for saving data.
usual CDN's (like cloudflare) block request from device.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.